# Unable to send mail using nodemailer nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am unable to connect to smtp server using nodemailer, I have tried with **C#** with the same configuration and C# was successful but with node i keep getting errors. Here is my configuration:

```
let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'subdomain.server.tld',
    port: 587,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: `user\user`,
        pass: "pass",
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});
```

and here is how am sending an email

```
transport.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@mail.com',
    to: 'recipient@mail.com',
    subject: 'Test mail',
    html: '<h1>This is a test mail</h1>'
}, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    } else {
        console.log('sent', info);
    }
});
```

I have tried with making `secure: false`, removing `tls` but nothing seems to work. The errors am getting are

```
{ Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
 code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

and when `secure: false` I get `Unrecognized authentication type`.

Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: As per the nodemailer docs, ports 587 and 25 default to {secure: false}, port 465 allows TLS use. Apart from that, in your auth property, are you using template literals? In which case you need to use `${yourval}` within the back-ticks.

Comment: am not using template literals in my auth property, i just used back ticks because user has a backslash in it @KVNam

Comment: I think that might be a problem. Backslash is an escape character in JS. Perhaps you should use `user\\user` to escape the backslash.

Comment: Well i was initially doing `"user\\user"` but it still was not working @KVNam

Comment: If STARTTLS is supported by your SMTP server, maybe you could try  - changing the port to 465 OR with {port: 587, secure: false} add {requireTLS:true}

Comment: I believe an SMTPS server would accept {secure:true}, but SMTP needs {requireTLS:true} as the connection starts as plaintext and then is upgraded to TLS.

Comment: @KVNam i decided to go with https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs, even this has its own problems, callback is called twice, first one is no connection has been established while second one is timedout but strangely enough the email is delivered

Comment: thanks for the alternative and the heads up. Looking to use it an project